# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException

Tags: java, tomcat, glassfish

```
StandardWrapperValve[PushFormController]: Servlet.service() for servlet PushFormController threw exception
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/client/ClientProtocolException
    at ru.berkanasoft.crm.controller.PushFormController.doPost(PushFormController.java:63)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:706)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.service(StandardWrapper.java:1580)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:258)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:160)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.doInvoke(StandardPipeline.java:652)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardPipeline.invoke(StandardPipeline.java:591)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebPipeline.invoke(WebPipeline.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.doService(CoyoteAdapter.java:371)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:238)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy$WorkerThreadRunnable.run(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:137)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1621)
    at org.glassfish.web.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1471)
    ... 31 more
```

On 63 line of code, I create object BroadcastPush which have some imports from org.apache.http, so when I run this code just from Main everything is ok, but when I run this code from HttpServlet everything is crushing

I have this exception when my BroadcastPush have this imports which I use to make a request to another server

```
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpUriRequest;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.RequestBuilder;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClients;
```

I tried to clean mvn project, so it didn't help

this lines of code are making request to server

```
HttpClient httpClient = HttpClients.createDefault();
        HttpUriRequest request;
        request = RequestBuilder.post("url");
        try {
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            InputStream input = response.getEntity().getContent();
            StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
            while (input.available() > 0) {
                output.append((char)input.read());
            }
            result = output.toString();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Also there are dependencies

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpcore -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpclient -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.10</version>
        </dependency>
 <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.servlet/javax.servlet-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.1</version>
        </dependency>
```

and some others...

Comment: Your runtime classpath is not right

Comment: @RomainHippeau I am compiling this project with idea. So, you think that this is an idea problem?

Comment: You have a runtime problem not a build problem. Show what you are doing in runtime